# How to make a generic close button for angular ui-views?

Tags: angularjs, ng-view, angularjs-rootscope

I need a function where I can use $window.history.back() to be called from every view regardless of what controller is controlling that page.

```
.run(['$rootScope', '$state', 'CommonUserModel', 'InitialiseService','$window', function($rootScope, $state, $window, commonUserModel, initialiseService) {

    $rootScope.link = function(){
        $window.history.back();
    };
```

So I have this function put in the app module. Injected window object because it complained about it. But now it also complains that it "Cannot read property 'back' of undefined".

I am calling this function with $rootScope from other controllers as I read through StackOverflow. I had to inject $rootScope to other controllers like this.

```
homeViewModule.controller("simDetailsController", [ '$rootScope','$scope', 'ModalDialogService', 'CommonTagModel', '$location','$window',
                                        function($scope, modalDialogService, commonTagModel, $location, $window,$rootScope) { 
self.link = function(){
   $rootScope.link();};
```

Can you give me an advice? 
Keep in mind that I am pretty newbie on AngularJS I still don't get this messy, complex framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order in which you have injected `$window` & `$rootScope` in the parameters list does not match the string array list.
You have mentioned `'$window'` as the 5th element in the string array, while, it is the 3rd element in the parameters list.
Also, in your code, `'$rootScope'` is the 1st element in the string array, while, it is the 6th element in the parameters list.

Replace the first lines in both of your code snippets with these:

`.run(['$rootScope', '$state', 'CommonUserModel', 'InitialiseService','$window', function($rootScope, $state, commonUserModel, initialiseService, $window) {`

`homeViewModule.controller("simDetailsController", [ '$rootScope','$scope', 'ModalDialogService', 'CommonTagModel', '$location','$window',
                                        function($rootScope, $scope, modalDialogService, commonTagModel, $location, $window) {`

Comment: actually you are right there was a problem in the app module list. But not in controllers. Actually, in the controller, do I have to do the window injection again? It was legacy code, because before I was injecting it and putting the same function to every controller which was why I thought there must be better way.

Comment: Perfect it worked. And in one controller, I only injected $rootScope; in the other, I did both $rootScope and $window. So both is working means that I don't really need window in controllers. Saves me a bit of typing.

Answer (score 0):

You should use routes:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route

Comment: We are using ui.router (ui-view) instead for routing. But we can review it. I still didn't see anything about how to make a close button for those views. you mean I should each time write an href to close button?

Comment: setTimeout(function() {
         $window.history.back();
    },100);